# merge cells using multirow package

Tags: pdftex, multirow, texshop, booktabs

I have the following code for a table:

```
\bgroup
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{table}[ht]
\textbf{\caption{My Table}} % title of Table
\centering % used for centering table
\begin{tabular}{ c|ccc } 
 \hline
 Col1 & Col2 & Col3 & Col4\\[5pt]
 \hline
 \multirow{2}{*}{Merged Cell} & A12 & A13 & A14\\ 
 \cmidrule(lr){2-4}
  & A22 & A23 & A24 \\ 
\hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\egroup
```

When I run this code, I find that the vertical line between the 1st and 2nd column is discontinuous. Not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Booktabs` adds vertical padding around its rules (`aboverulesep` and `belowrulesep`), which explains the discontinuity. Setting these to `-0.2pt` (half the thickness of a standard line) solves the problem.

You also can load `boldline` to emulate the variable thickness of booktabs rules, but you loose the possibility to trim  `\cmidrule`s.

Here is  an example of both solutions:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{multirow, booktabs, caption, boldline, cellspace}
\captionsetup{font=bf}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{8pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{\cellspacetoplimit}

    \begin{document}

\bgroup
\aboverulesep = -0.2pt
\belowrulesep = -0.2pt
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{table}[!ht]
  \caption{My Table} % title of Table
  \centering % used for centering table
  \begin{tabular}{ c|ccc }
    \toprule
    Col1 & Col2 & Col3 & Col4 \\[5pt]
    \midrule
    \multirow{2}{*}{Merged Cell} & A12 & A13 & A14 \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-4}
                                 & A22 & A23 & A24 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\egroup

\vskip 1cm
\begin{table}[!ht]
  \caption{My Table} % title of Table
  \centering % used for centering table
  \begin{tabular}{ c|Sccc }
    \hlineB{2}
    Col1 & Col2 & Col3 & Col4 \\
    \hlineB{1.5}
    \multirow{2}{*}[-4.6pt]{Merged Cell} & A12 & A13 & A14 \\
    \clineB{2-4}{1.5}
                                         & A22 & A23 & A24 \\
    \hlineB{2}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]